# Can't empty trash on Mac

Tags: terminal, trash, macos

Recently every time I try to delete files, my OS asks me to type in a password.  After I type in password, the files are deleted from the folder, but it doesn't free up space and the files don't show up in the trash, so I can't empty the trash.  I've tried troubleshooting different ways from searching on Google and Apple forums:

- I don't have Time Machine enabled.
- I have OS X 10.7.5.
- I've deleted over 100 GB of files, but I still only have 7 GB.
- I've tried typing in Terminal:

  ```
  sudo tmutil disablelocal
  ```
- I've tried typing in Terminal:

  ```
  resetpassword
  ```
- I've tried typing in Terminal:

  ```
  sudo rm -r /.cleverfiles
  ```

Any other suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. Try using something like DiskInventoryX to find out what is using the space and let's go from there.

Comment: Have you tried [repairing disk permissions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560)?

Comment: Is yours an Administrator, Standard, or Managed user account?

Comment: Have you tried [Trash It](http://nonamescriptware.com/downloads/)?

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your advice, but I found out how to fix. It took me a few tries, but I followed these instructions from the below link.  Just in case anyone else has this issue.  http://www.cnet.com/news/what-to-do-if-os-x-asks-for-passwords-when-managing-files/

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem on one of the Macs in my office.

I couldn't solve it directly, so I chose to delete the account, by backing up of all the important folders/files into another partition. Alternatively, you may move it out of the home folder to another folder (e.g. /Users/Shared/) temporarily. I deleted the user account and created a new one, which will solve problems with permissions, clear hidden data in the account and/or configuration problems like you are currently experiencing.